# Create Subsite from Modern SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, site-collection, sub-site, architecture

I was confused to create subsite on multiple scenarios, I saw it was not recommended to use or create subsite now.

1. Why it stopped to create subsite?
2. And how to manage similar way to create subsites (Hubsites -> site pages)?

Comment: Hi, does my below answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

> Classic SharePoint architecture is typically built using a hierarchical system of site collections and sub-sites, with inherited navigation, permissions, and site designs. Once built, this structure can be **inflexible and difficult to maintain**. In the modern SharePoint experience, sub-sites are not recommended. In the new "flat" world of modern SharePoint, plan to create one site for each discrete topic, task, or unit of work.
>
> This will allow you to **easily distribute management and accountability for each content collection** and support your ability to move sites around in your navigational architecture without breaking links. Moreover, when a topic is no longer needed, you can easily archive or delete a site with minimal impact.

In the new flat world, you have several ways to connect sites and content to each other as part of your information architecture toolkit:

- Use “roll up” web parts such as News, Highlighted content, or Sites to dynamically surface content from other sites in an existing site.
- Use inline hyperlinks to provide additional detail about a topic to provide more information to your reader (as demonstrated in the previous bullet).
- Add explicit links to related sites in your site navigation.
- **Connect families of related sites using hubs**.

**Source**: [Introduction to SharePoint information architecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/information-architecture-modern-experience)

Also, check below related references which are very helpful:

1. [Benefits to creating a flat site structure in SharePoint Online](https://sharegate.com/blog/sharepoint-information-architecture-benefits-flat-site-structure)
2. [Why flat SharePoint Site Architecture makes total sense](https://sharepointmaven.com/why-flat-sharepoint-site-architecture-makes-total-sense/)
3. [Modernizing SharePoint Architecture: Go Flat](https://www.softlanding.ca/blog/modernizing-sharepoint-architecture-go-flat/)